# If I send someone a google search results link, am I sending them any information about me?

Tags: web-application

When I do a google search, there's a lot of stuff in the URL for the results page:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+this+here&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=8G6gUtGnJIOh0QXt-4HYDg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAA&biw=1239&bih=806&dpr=1#q=security

https://www.google.com/search
?q=why+is+this+here
&source=lnms
&sa=X
&ei=8G6gUtGnJIOh0QXt-4HYDg
&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAA&biw=1239
&bih=806
&dpr=1
#q=security
```

What is all this stuff, and do I care if someone else sees it when I share a link to this page with them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to know that, Read
[The Ultimate Guide to the Google Search Parameters](http://moz.com/ugc/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-google-search-parameters) and [Advanced Google Search](http://jwebnet.net/advancedgooglesearch.html#basicSearchURI). The google search query structure is broken down into chunks and has detailed information about their purpose. You will get to know what the parameters in your search queries are.

The following are some of the decodings of Google's search query syntax.

*Basic Search URL:*

```
https://www.google.com/search?
hl=en
&q=test
&btnG=Google+Search
```

*Advanced Search URI*

```
https://www.google.com/search?
as_q=test (query string)
&hl=en (language)
&num=10 (number of results [10,20,30,50,100])
&btnG=Google+Search
&as_epq= (complete phrase)
&as_oq= (at least one)
&as_eq= (excluding)
&lr= (language results. [lang_countrycode])
&as_ft=i (filetype include or exclude. [i,e])
&as_filetype= (filetype extension)
&as_qdr=all (date [all,M3,m6,y])
&as_nlo= (number range, low)
&as_nhi= (number range, high)
&as_occt=any (terms occur [any,title,body,url,links])
&as_dt=i (restrict by domain [i,e])
&as_sitesearch= (restrict by [site])
&as_rights= (usage rights [cc_publicdomain,cc_attribute,cc_sharealike,cc_noncommercial,cc_nonderived]
&safe=images (safesearch [safe=on,images=off])
&as_rq= (similar pages)
&as_lq= (pages that link)
&gl=us (2-digit country code in lowercase)
&btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky
```

Comment: You still haven't explained the parameters listed in the question. Could you edit your answer and add the missing bits?

Comment: @RobW I believe It is better to educate the user to discover the answer instead of just giving the answer.