# Unknown URL parameters in google query

Tags: google, url

I received an email which is classified as "potentially malicious" by my email program (Thunderbird), where links are actually a google URL query with extra parameters:

For example, the *displayed* text of the link is `www.example.com/` but the *actual link* is `https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.example.com/&sa=D&ust=1535125407413000&usg=AFQjCNFsIVH5f4lBiIzr6njucxAoYFqy5A`

I searched everywhere the meaning of those extra tags `sa=`, `ust=` and `usg=` but there is no official reference about it, and for example, the links provided in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46507) seem outdated...

Also, I just noticed this is not a search, but an URL query (`www.google.com/url?`).

Is there something to worry about in this e-mail? Does anyone have an explanation of these URL parameters? How was this link made?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of the parameters, but that the URL given in the links text and the real URL of the link point to different domains - which is a common technique in phishing mails.

To cite from [Thunderbird’s Scam Detection](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbirds-scam-detection#w_protecting-yourself-from-scams):

> Thunderbird's automatic scam filtering
>  ...
>  It looks for
>   characteristics in messages that are common in scam messages, for
>   example:
>  ...
>  **Links where the text doesn't match the server
>   name** (for example, the text of the message might say
>   "https://secure.example.com" but the link actually goes to
>   "http://phishing.example.com" instead). Phishers do this to fool you
>   into going to their site. Unfortunately some legitimate mailing lists
>   also do this with redirectors for tracking purposes.

Comment: Yes I understood that, and then that led me to my question: should I worry about a seemingly harmless google URL? Can this type of URL be used as a phishing one?

Comment: @PlasmaBinturong: In this specific case the URL is probably no problem since Google makes sure that this can not be used as a simple open redirect. Also, the link text actually describes where it is going correctly. But in general links which look like they are for a trusted domain but actually redirect to another can lead to successful phishing, as can do cases where the link text is for a different domain than the link target. In both cases the user might have trust into the target because the link text or target URL actually look familiar.